# Pod can not connect to Cisco Packet Tracer API

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm new to kubernetes. I'm having problem with connecting Cisco SDN network controller to pod in kubernetes. My system is:

1. SDN running in Cisco Packet Tracer. It open an API on port 58000
2. Docker image used to run solution. This app access API port 58000 to retrieve data from SDN
3. Kubernetes
4. Confluent Kafka Cloud

When I deploy container image on Docker, the app is able to connect to the API port 58000.

```
docker run -d --net='host' --env RUNTYPE=-1 --env BROKERHOSTPORT=pkc-lzvrd.us-west4.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092 --env KAFKAPRODUCETOPIC=cisco-topic --env CLOUDUSERNAME=user --env CLOUDPASSWORD=api_key dockerhubaccount/cisco-app
```

However, when I deploy yml file by kubernetes, pod could not connect to the API due to connect refused. Here is my yml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: cisco
spec:
selector:
matchLabels:
app: cisco
replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: cisco
spec:
hostNetwork: true # share network with host
containers:
- name: cisco
image: dockerhubaccount/cisco-app
ports:
- containerPort: 58000
env:
- name: RUNTYPE
value: "-1"
- name: BROKERHOSTPORT
value: "pkc-lzvrd.us-west4.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092"
- name: CLOUDUSERNAME
value: "username"
- name: CLOUDPASSWORD
value: "api_key"
- name: KAFKAPRODUCETOPIC
value: "cisco-app"

I tried to run kubectl port-forward but it doesn't work.
Kafka Cloud is reachable in both mode. So I suppose there is something wrong when python script running inside container try to call localhost from pod. Here is python script used to call API port 58000

## Login to Packet tracer SDN on port 58000

def login(session):
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

```
  json_data = {
  'username': 'user',
  'password': 'pass!',
  }

  try:
    response = session.post('http://localhost:58000/api/v1/ticket', headers=headers, json=json_data)
  except Exception as e:
    print("ERROR: Make sure packet tracer is running:", e)
    return ""
```

I did a lot of research of kubernetes network but it doesn't work out.
Could you please help me to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Here is an error throwing from container when running in Kubernetes
ERROR: Make sure packet tracer is running: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=58000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/ticket (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa23354a370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
ERROR: Cannot get ticket from packet tracer SDN

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem coming from minikube. It does not allow pod access to app bonded only to localhost(127.0.0.1)
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/host-access/
Thanks